# Upgrade image in Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

Hi I have created custom image and I have used it for my Virtual Machine. Anyone can help me how can I upgrade image without any downtime ? I don't want to manually log in to machine and change things for me it would be better just to point to new image (upgraded one) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could spin up a new VM based on the upgraded image, redirect your traffic to this VM, then spin down the old VM.